# What are the avatar's supplements (hats)?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a new feature of various amusing added features for your avatar (hats). Theis seems to be a new feature. What is the origin of this feature?

Comment: I got 19 hats. I am very proud!

Comment: Now, they are all gone.

Comment: "all we are is dust in the wind"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the stackexchange winter bash: http://winterba.sh/

I'm a little puzzled as to the point of it all, but it seems like good fun. What I can't figure out is why it doesn't work with pictures. it only seems to work if you don't have a picture.

Comment: +Yury has a picture and a hat.

Comment: Huh. I can't figure out how to get my hat on.

Comment: Ah ok. I had to login to winterba.sh first.

Comment: I manage to put my hat on without logining to anything but the main site. (Anyway, nice hat Suresh!)

Comment: the point of it is a marketing gimmick to eg increase exposure, "branding", activity etc. one that slipped thru the cracks this time (ie passed thru the general/usual strong resistance). for humorless theoreticians it might seem useless or pointless. looking thru old archives, in the past other marketing gimmicks have been resoundly rejected by this "community".